# Initialie a Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to change table name dynamically based on parameter year. For example, in year 2019:

```
var qry= db.Forms2019.Where(x=>x.Active==true).OrderBy(x=>x.Name)
```

in year 2020:

```
vary qry= db.Forms2020.Where(x=>x.Active==true).OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
```

So I am using switch case. I have question how to initialize the qry here?

```
 public ActionResult Index(string year){
    var qry=??;
    switch(year){
         case "2019": 
             qry=db.Forms2019;
             break;
         case "2020":
            qry=db.Forms2020;
            break;
       }
      return View(qry);
 }
```

Comment: **Never pass an `IQueryable<T>` to a View!** - you need to materialize it first!

Comment: Do `Forms2019` and `Forms2020` contain the same entity type? If not, then it's a lot harder to do...

Comment: Yes, they return the same entity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `switch` is fine (it's how I would do it) but I'd do it like so:

(You could use a *switch-expression* to make it more succinct, but that requires C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 but you tagged your question with `asp.net-mvc` which means you're probably using C# 7.x at the latest (as ASP.NET MVC doesn't run on .NET Core, and you can't use C# 8.0 with ASP.NET MVC)

This approach below only works if all the tables contain the same Entity type (or the types are covariant):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index( Int32? year ) {

    // I assume Forms2019, Forms2020, etc all use the `Form` entity type:
    IQueryable<Form> query = this.GetBaseQuery( year ?? DateTime.Utc.Year );
    if( query is null )
    {
        return this.NotFound( message: $"No forms for the year {year} exist." );
    }

    List<Form> list = await query
        .Where( f => f.Active )
        .OrderBy( f => f.Name )
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return this.View( model: list );
 }

private IQueryable<Form> GetBaseQuery( Int32 year )
{
    switch( year )
    {
    case 2019:
        return this.db.Forms2019;
    case 2020:
        return this.db.Forms2020;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Update:

Apparently `Forms2019` and `Forms2020` return different entity types which means you can't use a single `IQueryable<Form2019>` variable to hold an `IQueryable<Form2020>` query.

The solution is to use an interface - fortunately Entity Framework and Linq generally support this:

First, define `interface IForm` with those members we want to query by:

```
interface IForm
{
    Boolean Active { get; }
    String  Name   { get; }
}

partial class Form2019 : IForm
{
}

partial class Form2020 : IForm
{
}
```

Then change the code above to this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index( Int32? year ) {

    // I assume Forms2019, Forms2020, etc all use the `Form` entity type:
    IQueryable<IForm> query = this.GetBaseQuery( year ?? DateTime.Utc.Year );
    if( query is null )
    {
        return this.NotFound( message: $"No forms for the year {year} exist." );
    }

    List<IForm> list = await query
        .Where( f => f.Active )
        .OrderBy( f => f.Name )
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return this.View( model: list );
 }

private IQueryable<IForm> GetBaseQuery( Int32 year )
{
    switch( year )
    {
    case 2019:
        return (IQueryable<IForm>)this.db.Forms2019; // This works because IQueryable<T> is covariant over T.
    case 2020:
        return (IQueryable<IForm>)this.db.Forms2020;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I received error message "cannot implicityly convert type 'System.Data.Entitle.dbset<Forms2020> to System.linq.iqueryable.Forms..."

Comment: @user788448 That means that your `Forms2019` and `Forms2020` properties **do not** have the same entity type. Why did you say that they do share the same entity type? (There's a workaround: define an `IForm` interface with the `Active` and `Name` properties and add it to the actual entity types using a `partial` definition).

Comment: These two tables are exactly the same but names. Okay, I will try the IForm work around way. Thanks.

Comment: @user788448 Just because two types have the exact same members does not mean that they are the same type: actually in .NET it's the opposite: two types are **always** distinct types, no matter how similar they are - this is because the CLR does not support structural-typing, only nominative-typing.

Comment: Another question, I have a JoinModel.cs that includes public Forms2019 Forms2019 {get; set;}  public Forms2020 Forms2020 {get; set;}  Can I still use Interface to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: @user788448 Post that as a separate question.